# disabling or enabling a public component

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, game-component

I need to be able to disable only a specific component of an object publicly. I got a public component but I cant find any ways on the internet on how to disable and enable that component. Here's the code:

```
    public Component script;
    void Start()
    {
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        if (sliderchanged.drop == 1)
        {
            script.enabled = false; //this is the error
        }
        if (sliderchanged.drop == 0)
        {

        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: You write "this is the error". Do you actually get an error message with this code?

Comment: Yeah, it says "component does not contain a definition for enabled". Does that mean that enabling components is not possible?

Comment: The documentation says that the Component class does not have a property "enabled", and it is what this error message is telling you. What is this component exactly?

Comment: well, I am trying add graphics settings to my game and so on the main camera if they chose fast settings it would disable specific components and enable other components on the camera to increase fps and same for if i chose slow settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Try replacing your `Component` type to a `MonoBehavior`.

Then `script.enabled = false` will work.

---

**Explanation**

The `Component` is the base class for anything that can be attached to a gameobject, it is very barebones, and **does not support enabling/disabling**.

The `MonoBehavior` class inherits all the functionality of `Component` but adds some extra features. For your purposes, what's important is that it supports enabling/disabling via scripts or the inspector.

---

**Resources**

Here's a more detailed [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540747/what-is-the-difference-between-component-behaviour-and-monobehaviour-and-why-t#:%7E:text=MonoBehaviour%20inherits%20directly%20from%20Behaviour,SphereCollider%20inherits%20from%20that%20Collider%20.) which explains the differences  between Component, Behavior and Monobehavior if you're interested.